# Quick sort on an array

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I have an array A = |0.535|0.960|0.750|0.750|0.151|0.001|0.981|0.327|0.111|

I took the pivot as 0.535

I swapped A[1] = 0.960 with A[8] = 0.111 to get

A = |0.535|0.111|0.750|0.750|0.151|0.001|0.981|0.327|0.960|

Then I swapped A[2] = 0.750 with A[7] = 0.327 to get

A = |0.535|0.111|0.327|**0.750**|0.151|0.001|0.981|**0.750**|0.960|

Now I'm confused as to what to do next (0.75 is compared with 0.75) as the values 0.151 is less than pivot and 0.981 is greater than pivot. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are exactly looking for. However, if you want to know how quick sort works, let's go through your array. It should be mentioned that we are going to get the first most left element as pivot.

```js
    function qsort(x, lo, hi) {
      var i, p;
      if (lo >= hi) {
          return;
      }
      p = lo;
      for (i = lo + 1; i <= hi; i++) {
        if (x[i] < x[lo]) {
            swap(x, ++p, i);

         }
      }
    swap(x, lo, p);
    qsort(x, lo, p - 1);
    qsort(x, p + 1, hi);
    }
```

As you said you get 0.535 as pivot in the first step it will go through your elements from the second element(from pivot) and if it was smaller than chosen pivot, it will change that element's position with second element, if it found second element smaller it will change it with the third element's position and so on. At the end, it will change the pivot's position with position=total elements it has been larger than. So after choosing 0.535 the array would be like:

[ 0.111, 0.151, 0.001, 0.327, 0.535, 0.75, 0.981, 0.75, 0.96].

And after that pivot would be 0.111 and then array will be like:

[ 0.001, 0.111, 0.151, 0.327, 0.535, 0.75, 0.981, 0.75, 0.96 ].

again pivot = 0.151 and array:

[ 0.001, 0.111, 0.151, 0.327, 0.535, 0.75, 0.981, 0.75, 0.96 ]

again pivot = 0.75 and array:

[ 0.001, 0.111, 0.151, 0.327, 0.535, 0.75, 0.981, 0.75, 0.96 ]

again pivot = 0.981 and array:

[ 0.001, 0.111, 0.151, 0.327, 0.535, 0.75, 0.96, 0.75, 0.981 ]

again pivot = 0.96 and array:

[ 0.001, 0.111, 0.151, 0.327, 0.535, 0.75, 0.75, 0.96, 0.981 ]